# Printing out the correct data from file

Tags: java, file-io, printing

How do i print the correct data, because whenever i print, it will just print out the last person's data. For Example, there is 2 data in the file like this. I want my output to be like output 2, but i keep getting output 1.

**input:**

Bob Joe

23

Alie May

34

**output 1:**

Alie May 34

Alie May 34

**output 2:**

Bob Joe 23

Alie May 34

```
 private Player players = new Player();
 private List<Player> player = new ArrayList<Player>();

public void Read() throws IOException
{

    BufferedReader bs = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Player.txt"));


    while((line1 = bs.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] token = line1.split(" ");
        players.setfName(token[0]);
        players.setlName(token[1]);
        players.setScore(Integer.parseInt(bs.readLine()));

        player.add(players);
    }

    bs.close();
}

public void print()
{
    for(Player p : player)
    {   
        System.out.println(players.getfName() + " " + players.getlName() + " " + players.getScore());
    }
}
```

Comment: Call getters on variable p.

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to name the Player object "player" and the List<Player> as "players" so that you don't get confused when you code. Also helps when other people read it too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `players` is shared by `while loop`, the list have the same object `players`.

you should do as the following

```
while((line1 = bs.readLine()) != null)
{   
    Player players1 = new Player();
    String[] token = line1.split(" ");
    players1.setfName(token[0]);
    players1.setlName(token[1]);
    players1.setScore(Integer.parseInt(bs.readLine()));

    player.add(players1);
}
```

meanwhile, there is an error here

```
 System.out.println(players.getfName() + " " + players.getlName() + " " + players.getScore());
```

you should change `players` to `p`

hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the while loop. You are adding the same object `players` to the list. You need to create a new object for each of the entries in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.out.println(players.getfName() + " " + players.getlName() + " " + players.getScore());
```

since you are printing `players` which is having the information of player you have entered at last.

update line as follow:

```
System.out.println(p.getfName() + " " + p.getlName() + " " + p.getScore());
```